# Bootstrap 3: Affix navbar fade in and add object

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

1) I would like to fade in / ease in the navbar when user scroll down. Possible with css3 ease-in?

2) Would it possible to add an image (or the text) only in the fixed navbar? For example, on load Logo1 and on scroll Logo 2?

```
#nav.affix {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
```

}

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5jq88/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes it's possible with animation property and keyframes - http://jsfiddle.net/5jq88/1/
2. Second yes, just trigger the image/text appearing by the #nav.affix class

   ```
   #nav #nav-img {
      display:none;
   }
   #nav.affix #nav-img {
      display:inline-block;
   }
   ```